# While training the model, the loss will increase at the beginning of a new epoch

Tags: pytorch, training-data, loss-function

I'm using pytorch to do an unsupervised anomaly detection task. When training a neural network(named DAGMM), the defined loss function is based on the reconstruction error of the sample.

I divided the data into 5318 batches for training. But the number of samples is not divisible by batchsize. I think this is the reason, so I added the `drop_last` parameter. but it didn't work out.

```py
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                         batch_size=hyp['batch_size'], 
                         shuffle=shuffle, 
                         drop_last=True)
```

At the beginning of each epoch, the printed loss log will increase. I don’t know what the problem is.And here's some evaluation results and config while training:

```
Time 3366.28, Epoch [1/5], Iter [5300/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 21.5814, recon_error 21.7351, energy -6.3370 
Time 3408.99, Epoch [2/5], Iter [50/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 29.3530, recon_error 29.5780, energy -8.8175 
Time 3439.69, Epoch [2/5], Iter [100/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 21.5223, recon_error 21.6843, energy -6.3602 

Time 6853.50, Epoch [2/5], Iter [5300/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 21.0750, recon_error 21.5087, energy -8.3140 
Time 6899.28, Epoch [3/5], Iter [50/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 29.0018, recon_error 29.5963, energy -11.5204 
Time 6932.67, Epoch [3/5], Iter [100/5318], lr 0.0001 loss 21.1673, recon_error 21.6118, energy -8.4462
```

Comment: It is understandable. The loss is averaged across all batches in an epoch, so it’s obvious that the first batch will have high loss. Btw, you might want to format your question.

Comment: I don't really understand what is your problem. Can you edit the question to clarify it?

Comment: Sorry, I have re-edited.